# How can use OutputStreamWriter forUpdate some line?

Tags: java, file, utf-8

I add utf8 Character with this code, all is ok. 
I want update some line at file. 
When I use RandomAccessFile utf8 Character fail.
How can use OutputStreamWriter forUpdate some line?

```
// Add 
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, "UTF-8");
out.write(line);
out.write("\n");
out.close();
fos.close();

// Update 
lineNumber=100;
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
randomAccessFile.seek(lineNumber * (line.length() + 1));
randomAccessFile.writeBytes(line);
randomAccessFile.writeBytes("\n");
randomAccessFile.close();
return lineNumber;
```